# Tweepy import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I installed tweepy module using command in mac UNIX shell:

```
pip install tweepy
```

but when I try to import tweepy after running python, it returns:

```
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

Any ideas what could be happening here? The module is obviously installed but this error is still occurring. I tried importing some other installed modules and they work normally ...

Comment: Are you sure the module is installed? Do you  have multiple versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

You should first update your module.
Here is the python code you can use to update it :

```
import pip
from subprocess import call
for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

Then try installing tweepy, or you can use the Github version of tweepy if you want to avoid all of the effort.

Answer (score 0):

does your file (py) have the same name as the module you are importing?
this sometimes causes problems with the python compiler.

(ref: [Twitter module python 'module' object has no attribute Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979323/twitter-module-python-module-object-has-no-attribute-oauth) )

I had that problem too. Try changing the name of your file.

Comment: if that was the case then `import tweety` would have worked but it would have imported itself, so using anything within `tweety` would have failed

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting python versions here. `pip` installed into one python version, and your default `python` command points to another version. Run `pip show tweepy` to see for which python version it did install:

```
$ pip show tweepy | grep Version
Version: 3.5.0
```

Then compare this to the version `python` points to:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

On my machine these two differed as well. So when I started `python` then `import tweepy` failed.

To solve that you can do one of those:

- use `pip` which matches your python version to install tweepy (in my case it would be `pip2.7 install tweepy`)
- use the python version for which you have installed tweepy (in my case it would mean to call `python3.5`)

Answer (score 0):

Try running: `sudo apt install python-pip`

and then run: `python3 -m pip install tweepy`

I hope that helps!