# Twitter module python 'module' object has no attribute Oauth

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

Im trying to follow this basic example [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/blob/master/ipynb/Chapter%201%20-%20Mining%20Twitter.ipynb).

Code

```
import twitter

# XXX: Go to http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new to create an app and get values
# for these credentials, which you'll need to provide in place of these
# empty string values that are defined as placeholders.
# See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth for more information 
# on Twitter's OAuth implementation.

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET =''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

# Nothing to see by displaying twitter_api except that it's now a
# defined variable

print twitter_api
```

But running the example throws the following error.

```
vagrant@lucid32:~$ python twitter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/home/vagrant/twitter.py", line 14, in <module>
    auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found that twitter.API worked for me even after installing twitter package and not python-twitter

Answer (score 4):

Don't name your scripts the same as modules you're import, as when python imports it first looks in script directory, so `twitter.py` is imported instead of `twitter` module.

And after you rename your file to something different with `twitter.py`, don't forget to remove it's compiled code (`twitter.pyc` and `tweepy.pyc`).

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what OS you are using. Is it Ubuntu or Debian?

If so, `apt-get install python-twitter` installs the wrong package for your needs. Install the correct package like so:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-twitter
sudo pip install twitter
```

Additionally, you should change the name of your program so that it isn't identical to the module you are importing.

Comment: Renamed it, doesnt change anything. Does `twit.py` work?

Comment: @KodeSeeker - in addition to my previous advice, I suspect you have the wrong twitter API installed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of twitter.oauth.Oauth, use twitter.Api

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                      consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                      access_token_key='access_token',
                      access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

[Details Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/2.0)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here is what helped  me out.
I first found out all the the packages that were related to twitter,which in my case were **tweepy** and **twitter**. I uninstalled both of them and re installed twitter. So far so good. It worked for me.

> help("modules")

The main problem was not with the OAuth but installation of multiple twitter packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I had `python-twitter` package installed. I kept getting the same exact error. By removing `python-twitter` like:

```
(!pip uninstall python-twitter)
```

in  `Ipython` console and installing twitter package now it works fine.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [tweepy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy) instead, I found it does a much better job of handling twitter authentication

```
import tweepy
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET =''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Comment: That gives me this error.
 File "tweepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/home/vagrant/tweepy.py", line 6, in <module>
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'

Comment: How did you install tweepy? It looks like python is looking in your home directory

Comment: @KodeSeeker - I don't intend to beat a dead horse, but you can't name your program the same as the module you are importing.

Comment: @Robᵩ it seems OP did it twice in a row :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give evidence that the solution provided by Rob, worked well for me. Apparently, the problem is that it was installed with apt-get and not pip, which may be give the right version of the library.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-twitter
sudo pip install twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oauth2 you may need to import as oauth in order for python to recognize the library.  I had this same problem a few days ago and that was the simple fix.