# How to get follower count using tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the follower count of companies and track it over time. I have over 200 000 companies so the code I currently have would literally take years to run with current api limit.

```
c = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id = a)
ids = []
for id in c.items():
   time.sleep(0.01)
   ids.append(id) '
```

In this code its one api hit for every follower. I was wondering if there is a function that just gives a follower count as a number? Also what is the twitter api limit?

Comment: If you just need the follower count, not the id's, you can get this information from the metadata of every tweet. Thus, provided that the companies you want to track have enough activity, using the streaming api would be the fastest way, besides with no rate limits. However, 200.000 companies is too much, you cannot track them using terms or screen_names... the maximum is 5000 id's (see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter)). Even with that limitation, it is your best chance... 200.000 with REST api rate limits would take you months to retrieve! Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each API requests returns at most 5000 followers IDs  at a time, to retrieve all the followers of the 200 000 companies, here is a very useful script from the book **Mining the social web** by Matthew A. Russell to solve the twitter api limit

to make robust twitter request and to access twitter's API **Matthew** defined these methods :

```
import sys
import time
from urllib2 import URLError
from httplib import BadStatusLine
import json
import twitter

def oauth_login():
    CONSUMER_KEY = ''
    CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
    OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''
    auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                               CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
    return twitter_api

def make_twitter_request(twitter_api_func, max_errors=10, *args, **kw):
# A nested helper function that handles common HTTPErrors. Return an updated
# value for wait_period if the problem is a 500 level error. Block until the
# rate limit is reset if it's a rate limiting issue (429 error). Returns None
# for 401 and 404 errors, which requires special handling by the caller.
    def handle_twitter_http_error(e, wait_period=2, sleep_when_rate_limited=True):
        if wait_period > 3600: # Seconds
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Too many retries. Quitting.'
            raise e
# See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses for common codes
        if e.e.code == 401:

            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered 401 Error (Not Authorized)'
            return None
        elif e.e.code == 404:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered 404 Error (Not Found)'
            return None
        elif e.e.code == 429:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered 429 Error (Rate Limit Exceeded)'
            if sleep_when_rate_limited:
                print >> sys.stderr, "Retrying in 15 minutes...ZzZ..."
                sys.stderr.flush()
                time.sleep(60*15 + 5)
                print >> sys.stderr, '...ZzZ...Awake now and trying again.'
                return 2
            else:
                raise e # Caller must handle the rate limiting issue
        elif e.e.code in (500, 502, 503, 504):
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered %iError. Retrying in %iseconds' %\
            (e.e.code, wait_period)
            time.sleep(wait_period)
            wait_period *= 1.5
            return wait_period
        else:
            raise e
# End of nested helper function
    wait_period = 2
    error_count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            return twitter_api_func(*args, **kw)
        except twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError, e:
            error_count = 0
            wait_period = handle_twitter_http_error(e, wait_period)
            if wait_period is None:
                return
        except URLError, e:
            error_count += 1
            print >> sys.stderr, "URLError encountered. Continuing."
            if error_count > max_errors:
                print >> sys.stderr, "Too many consecutive errors...bailing out."
                raise
        except BadStatusLine, e:
            error_count += 1
            print >> sys.stderr, "BadStatusLine encountered. Continuing."
            if error_count > max_errors:
                print >> sys.stderr, "Too many consecutive errors...bailing out."
                raise
```

here is the methods to retrieve the friends and the followers :

```
from functools import partial
from sys import maxint

def get_friends_followers_ids(twitter_api, screen_name=None, user_id=None,
friends_limit=maxint, followers_limit=maxint):
    # Must have either screen_name or user_id (logical xor)
    assert (screen_name != None) != (user_id != None),\
    "Must have screen_name or user_id, but not both"
    # See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids and
    # https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids for details
    # on API parameters
    get_friends_ids = partial(make_twitter_request, twitter_api.friends.ids,
                             count=5000)
    get_followers_ids = partial(make_twitter_request,twitter_api.followers.ids,
                               count=5000)
    friends_ids, followers_ids = [], []
    for twitter_api_func, limit, ids, label in [
                    [get_friends_ids, friends_limit, friends_ids, "friends"],
                    [get_followers_ids, followers_limit, followers_ids, "followers"]
                ]:
        if limit == 0: continue
        cursor = -1
        while cursor != 0:

            # Use make_twitter_request via the partially bound callable...
            if screen_name:
                response = twitter_api_func(screen_name=screen_name, cursor=cursor)
            else: # user_id
                response = twitter_api_func(user_id=user_id, cursor=cursor)
            if response is not None:
                ids += response['ids']
                cursor = response['next_cursor']
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Fetched {0} total {1} ids for{2}'.format(len(ids),
                                                    label, (user_id or screen_name))
            # XXX: You may want to store data during each iteration to provide  
            # an additional layer of protection from exceptional circumstances
            if len(ids) >= limit or response is None:
                break
    # Do something useful with the IDs, like store them to disk...
    return friends_ids[:friends_limit], followers_ids[:followers_limit]

# Sample usage
twitter_api = oauth_login()
friends_ids, followers_ids =get_friends_followers_ids(twitter_api,
                                                      screen_name="SocialWebMining",
                                                      friends_limit=10,
                                                      followers_limit=10)
print friends_ids
print followers_ids
```

Comment: Could you walk me through what the code does cause its not working for me.

Comment: sorry i forgot to define the 2 functions : **make_twitter_request** and **oauth_login** i'll edit the script, it works perfectly for me !

Comment: Its telling me: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'

Comment: Did you install twitter package using pip ? **pip install twitter** ?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979323/twitter-module-python-module-object-has-no-attribute-oauth

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve all followers right now its only the first 5000?

Comment: yes you can retrieve more than 5000 followers, **friends_ids, followers_ids =get_friends_followers_ids(twitter_api,
                          screen_name="briantford", 
                          friends_limit=10,
                          followers_limit=500000)**